# Find the value of p for the functionto be continous

Tags: continuity

In the following function .

[image]

We have to determine the value of p , *if possible*, so that the function is
continuous at $x = 1/2$.

I tried and found the LHS of function at $x=1/2$ that is $(-1/4)$.

But how could we comment on RHS

Comment: Your left limit is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit $x\to \frac{1}{2}_+$ of $f$ formally gives us

$$\frac{\sqrt{2\frac{1}{2}-1}}{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{2\frac{1}{2}-1}}-2}=\frac{0}{0}.$$

This is indeterminate form, and so we can either use L'Hopital's rule (however, given the context, I will avoid this), or we can compute this limit by hand by the common trick of multiplying by the conjugate:

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}_+} \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{4+\sqrt{2x-1}}-2}= \lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}_+} \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}(\sqrt{4+\sqrt{2x-1}}+2)}{\sqrt{2x-1}}=\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}_+} \sqrt{4+\sqrt{2x-1}}+2=4.$$

Is this sufficient to help you finish the problem?

Comment: I could not understand what do you mean by common trick

Comment: I mean that this is a technique which is often used in these types of problems. As another example: $\frac{\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-1}-1}$ can be manipulated by multiplying by $1$ in a clever way: multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x-1}+1$ (the conjugate of the denominator). If you do the calculations you will see the denominator will simplify significantly. Oftentimes, this results in the necessary cancellation to compute the limit.

Answer (score 1):

> Left limit

Put $t=x-\frac{1}{2}$.
then for $x>\frac{1}{2}$

$$f(x)=\frac{1-\cos(\pi t)  }{ 1-\cos(2\pi t) }\sim \frac {\frac{\pi^2 t^2 }{2}} {\frac{4\pi^2 t^2  }{ 2  }   }$$
the left limit is $\frac{1}{4}$.

> Right limit

put $\sqrt{2x-1}=4u$, then
$$f(x)=\frac{4u}{2(\sqrt{1+u}-1 )}\sim \frac{4u}{2\frac{u}{2}}$$ which goes to $4$ when $u $ goes to $0^+$.

So we have

$$\frac{1}{4}=\lim_{x\to (\frac{1}{2})^-} f(x)\neq \lim_{x\to (\frac{1}{2})^+}f(x)=4$$

$p$ doesn't exist.

Comment: The function you have used is for x<1/2

Comment: Yes , I am okay with that